# How to do a Thread Dump on EMR Presto service

Tags: amazon-emr, presto

By going to the Amazon EMR summary page, I can only see command for how to connect to the master node with `hadoop` user:

```sh
ssh -i ~/data-abc.pem hadoop@ip-10-90-28-13.ec2.internal
```

By doing `jps` with `hadoop` user, I don't see presto jvm process. When I use `ps -ef|grep presto` find out the java process ID and do `jstack -l <PID>`, it gave me error of :

`Operation not permitted`

So how can I really dump the presto threads, but not hadoop threads..

Comment: Can it be the Presto service runs as a `presto` user?

Comment: yes, I think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Presto service is run as `presto` OS user.
Thus, you need to invoke `jstack` as that user too.

For example

```
sudo -u presto jstack -l <pid>
```

Comment: that's the problem.. I don't have sudo access, nor presto user password. Don't find where the password stored on AWS either..

Comment: I would assume the service account has no password.

Comment: No password  is not the same as empty password. When there is no password you cannot log in interactively.

Comment: Awesome.. you perfectly answered my question. Thanks!